# How to remove a user from group in Linux?

Tags: linux, users

I added a user to a group with `usermod -aG user group`, when it should of been `usermod -aG group user`. Is there a command to remove the user from the specific group? I checked the man page for usermod, but I don't see an option to remove the user from the group. Is there a command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `deluser` command does that

```
deluser user group
```

Comment: No. The manual states: "If called with two non-option arguments, deluser will remove a user from a specific group."

Comment: I just saw that in the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Get a full list of the groups the user is in (for example, by running `sudo -u <user> groups` as root), then use `usermod -G` without the `-a` option to directly modify the list of groups.  Without `-a`, the `-G` option replaces the current list of supplementary groups for that user with the new list.  Note that the `-G` option expects the list of groups you pass to it to be comma separated, but most things that list the groups a user is in will produce a space separated list.
- Directly edit `/etc/groups` and `/etc/gshadow` to remove the user from the group.  Ideally, do so using the `vigr` and `vigr -s` commands (they'll make all the special checks to ensure that the files are (mostly) sane).